# Appium - Developer profile

Tags: ios7, appium

I created a IPA file with Developer provisioning profile and installed the application on my device successfully. When I try to invoke my application through appium, it always throws the following error message.

```
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-09-16 15:50:42.184 instruments[3425:507] Permission to debug com.ampchroma.simplexgrinnell.uat.mobilecontainer was denied.  The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
```

Logs:

> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 info: [debug] Spawning
>   instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
>   com.ampchroma.simplexgrinnell.uat.mobilecontainer -e UIASCRIPT
>   /Users/rsangili/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
>
> info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch
>   timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-09-16 15:50:42.184
>   instruments[3425:507] Permission to debug
>   com.ampchroma.simplexgrinnell.uat.mobilecontainer was denied.  The app
>   must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting
>   Recording
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
>
> info: [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup info: [debug] Attempting
>   to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3 info: [debug] Killall
>   iPhoneSimulator
>
> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
>
> info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
>   com.ampchroma.simplexgrinnell.uat.mobilecontainer -e UIASCRIPT
>   /Users/rsangili/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-09-16 15:50:49.931
>   instruments[3428:507] Permission to debug
>   com.ampchroma.simplexgrinnell.uat.mobilecontainer was denied.  The app
>   must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting
>   Recording
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
>
> info: [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup info: [debug] We exceeded
>   the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start;
>   failing launch info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture info: [debug]
>   Killing the simulator process
>
> info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning app state.
>
> info: [debug] No folders found to remove
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
>
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.303 ms - 104
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.354 ms - 104
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.228 ms - 104
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

Comment: It seems like you're using simulator build. Try with device build.

Comment: I am using the device build. Can you please let me know the reason why do you suspect the simulator build?

Comment: When I try with simulator build on the real device, I am facing the same issue. Later I have changed it to Device build it was working fine.

Comment: @RameshSangili any luck. I'm having exact same problem and its signed with iPhone Developer identity

Comment: Please update your question with your desired capabilities and server arguments. The logs don't tell me if you're using a bundleId or app path to specify the target application.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem last week. My developer had to sign the IPA with the device UDID, then it worked. Providing the UDID in the appium ios settings is not enough.

Here are some decent resources:

[Appium on real iOS devices](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/appium-setup/real-devices.md)

[Detailed video on your exact error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y52Z3kp6yQ8&feature=youtu.be)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** that app should be in debug mode to do automation and signed with the developer certificate.

> For Instruments/Appium to connect to the application on a real device
>   you need to Have the .ipa file signed with a "Development" certificate
>   that includes the UDID of the target device You can not use a
>   "Distribution" certificate, which is what all App Store builds are
>   signed with.

---

You can try below other options, any of them might work for you:

1) make sure you are using correct path of xcode in appium app.

2) firstly install the app from xcode on your device and then try to run through appium app.

3) make sure you are using correct app path,if you're running on real device it should be the path of "debug-iPhones" otherwise "debug0iPhoneSimulator" directory

4) make sure you're giving correct udid of device and bundleid of your app in appium app